# $\mathbb{D}^*\times \mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{R}^{4}$ simply connected

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}^*\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the punctured unit disk, we can say that the product $\mathbb{D}^*\times \mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ is a simply connected domain?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $S^1\times\Bbb R^n\subset\Bbb R^{n+2}$? [By the way, your dimension in your title is wrong.]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\pi_1 (X \times Y, (x_0,y_0))=\pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(Y, y_0)$.